# RENAME COLUMN IF EXISTS in H2

Tags: h2

I have a H2 sql script file that is executed everytime the application is updated or when the database was not created previously.

So, everything inside the script file relies on "IF NOT EXISTS" or "IF EXISTS" verification check.

Because of that, I have problem creating SQL to rename columns and a cannot find a way to do this, because if the rename statement is executed more than once, I got an error about column inexistance.

I`ve tried the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE X RENAME COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS Y TO Z;
```

Answer (score 2):

[office doc](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_alter_column)
`ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN NAME RENAME TO TEXT;`

Answer (score -2):

I`ve created one function to fill my needs, as follows. If you have a different approach, please let me know. tks!

```sql
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS RENAME_COLUMN_IF_EXISTS;
CREATE ALIAS RENAME_COLUMN_IF_EXISTS AS  $$
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
@CODE
void renameColumnIfExists(final Connection conn, final String tableName, final String cOld, final String cNew) throws SQLException {
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ? AND COLUMN_NAME = ?"); 

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    try {
        ps.setString(1, tableName);
        ps.setString(2, cOld);

        ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();

        if (results.next()) {
            if (results.getInt(1) > 0) {
                ps.close();

                sql = new StringBuffer()
                    .append("ALTER TABLE").append(" ")
                    .append(tableName).append(" ")
                    .append("RENAME COLUMN").append(" ")
                    .append(cOld).append(" ")
                    .append("TO").append(" ")
                    .append(cNew);
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        ps.close();
    }
}
$$;

CALL RENAME_COLUMN_IF_EXISTS ('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```